# graphqlHTTP is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql

Here is my simple graphql express app

```
const express = require('express');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');

const app = express();
app.use(
    '/graphql',
    graphqlHTTP({
      graphiql: true,
    })
  );

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("listening for request!");
});
```

I'm getting the following errors when I run it:

```
 graphqlHTTP({
    ^

TypeError: graphqlHTTP is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\PersonalProjects\GraphQL\server\app.js:7:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)  
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

How can I fix it

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphql):

> ```
> const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
> ```

Note that it uses destructuring equivalent to:

```
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;
```

`require('express-graphql')` returns an *object* with a *property* called `graphqlHTTP` that is the function you want to call.

You're trying to call the object itself as if it was a function.

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful. I hit this error while following a GraphQL in 40 minutes video tutorial dated Mar 2, 2019.

Answer (score 32):

Quentin's answer was on spot. Apparently the [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphql) was updated but some of the tutorials on YouTube were not. That's why there's a certain degree of confusion for learners like myself.
There are still outdated versions of the code like

This one: https://github.com/iamshaunjp/graphql-playlist/blob/lesson-36/server/app.js

This one: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Learn-GraphQL/blob/master/server.js

Or this one: https://github.com/bradtraversy/customerbase/blob/master/server.js

They should all be updated to

```
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
```

and then

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema:schema,
    graphiql:true
}));
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
const gqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');

app.use('/graphql', gqlHTTP.graphqlHTTP({
 // something
}))
```

Answer (score 9):

This code was written with an earlier version of `express-graphql`.

**Prior to v0.10.0**, you could use

```
var graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
```

**After v0.10.0**, you need to use

```
var { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to make it more clear:

Before "express-graphql" was returning a direct function or a class with the function and we could assign it to any variable like graphqlServer

`const graphqlServer = require('express-graphql');`

Now, it returns the whole object that has a function inside it named "graphqlHTTP". hence the code should be exactly

`const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');`

and to make a connection,

```
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    // your config
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue solved by the above answers.

For anyone wondering, express-graphql version 0.10.0 is where the relevant change started so you can check your package.json express-graphql dependency version number.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphql/v/0.9.0
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphql/v/0.10.0

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Setup**:

DO NOT USE YOUR OWN PARAMETER STRICTLY USE { graphqlHTTP }!!!!

Just mount express-graphql as a route handler:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
 
const app = express();
 
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: MyGraphQLSchema,
    graphiql: true,
  }),
);
 
app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 4K')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this approach:

```js
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
```

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin mentioned, you are trying to call the object itself as if it were a function.
You could update the following line to use destructuring:
i.e. Update
--> const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
to
--> const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');