# expressGraphQL is not a function

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, nodemon, macos-big-sur

I am learning GraphQL for my project using this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQL7tL2S0oQ&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified

and I get the error:

```
TypeError: expressGraphQL is not a function
at Object.<anonymous>
```

I have already tried:

- this solution: [graphqlHTTP is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760975/graphqlhttp-is-not-a-function)  - the program crashes all the same with {} parentheses and without them
- adding a semicolon after various lines

The code for now looks like this:

```
const express = require ('express')
const { expressGraphQL } = require('express-graphql')
const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
    graphiql: true,
})
)
app.listen(5000., () => console.log('Server Running'))
```

If I comment out this section:

```
app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
graphiql: true,
})
)
```

the code works perfectly fine both with {} parentheses and without them.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Please replace your expressGraphQL with graphqlHTTP as it was destructured

Use:

```
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
```

or

```
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP
```

This is because a method called graphqlHTTP exist in the express-graphql module and you are destructure with another method name that does not exist in the module

I also noticed that you have a dot after 5000 on the app.listen function.

Comment: I think this question is so popular because [this](https://buddy.works/tutorials/building-graphql-server-using-nodejs-and-express) tutorial gives incorrect instructions

Comment: and +1 also coming from [this tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/building-serverless-graphql-api-in-node-with-express-and-netlify/) (:

Comment: @fatiu: Very helpful, thanks.

Comment: I am also coming from the same tutorial. I opened a PR on the author's github repo fixing the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/ankitamasand/gql-server/pull/3

Comment: best answer! Also, you can use it as a reference  expressGraphQL using ``const { graphqlHTTP: expressGraphQL } = require('express-graphql');
``

Answer (score 18):

Use following as a solution.

```
const express = require('express');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;


const app = express();

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
    graphiql:true
}));

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Listning');
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Destructure graphqlHTTP from express-graphql

```
const { graphqlHTTP } = require("express-graphql");

app.use("/graphql", graphqlHTTP({ graphiql: true }));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
```

Note that it uses destructuring equivalent to:

```
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;
```

require('express-graphql') returns an object with a property called graphqlHTTP that is the function you want to call.

You're trying to call the object itself as if it was a function.`enter code here`

Comment: Can anyone explain why this destructuring is needed? I worked with graph before and you didnt have to call .graphqlHTTP. I worked the same way this persons tutorial is stating so I am just curious what changed in the last year or so and why this is now needed?